# Select columns via findMany and keep relationships in Laravel's Eloquent

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

I'm trying to get Posts and Authors. However, I only need the title of a post and the author information.

This is the query I'm running:

```
// I want post titles with IDs of 1, 2, 3, 4 and 5 and the author of each one
Post::with('author')->findMany([1, 2, 3, 4 , 5], ['post_title');
```

The resulting Collection has the `post_title` fine, but the author relationship is **null**.

However, if I run:

```
Post::findMany([1, 2, 3, 4, 5])->with('author');
```

I can access author in `$post->author->first_name`.

I don't understand why the relationship gets lost if I specify which columns I need.

So, how to query the posts table specifying which columns I'd like to select and also keeping the relationship with authors?

Comment: Why don't you try `Post::with('author')->find([1, 2, 3, 4 , 5]);`

Comment: Thanks, already tried that way. Author becomes null once I set the columns I want like `Post::with('author')->find([1, 2, 3, 4 , 5], ['post_title']);`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to select `Post` id, because when you use `with` method it mean you are using Laravel Eager Loading, Eager Load need `Post` id to load `author`

```
Post::with('author')->findMany([1, 2, 3, 4 , 5], ['id','post_title');
```